# setting up cron job for m2e pro

Tags: magento, cron, m2e

I need to import ebay listing in magento, but in m2pro there is always the message: "eBay 3rd Party Listings are being downloaded now. They will be available soon in Sell On eBay > Listings > 3rd Party. You can continue working with M2E Pro.".
The settings are right: " Import 3rd Party Listings Import" and "3rd Party Listings Synchronization" are enabled, but I have no ebay 3rd Party Listings in magento. 
M2e pro support replied that it is necessary setting up cron job, but I don't know which file I have to change and how.

Answer (score 1):

In M2ePro module, you can see etc directory. 
There are two files config.xm and system.xml. 
Please open the config.xml and check the following code: ( You can check this code in the bottom of that  file )

```
<crontab>
    <jobs>
        <M2ePro_cron>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>M2ePro/Cron::process</model>
            </run>
        </M2ePro_cron>
    </jobs>
...
</crontab>
```

This is just M2ePro extension.

Actually, I think you would update to the version 6.2.3 via Magento connect Manager. In this version, you can see 3rd Party Listings in backend ( Amazon->Manage Listings->3rd Party Listings)

Answer (score 1):

I have 6.2.3 version already. I have this code in config.xml:

```
    <crontab>
    <jobs>
        <M2ePro_cron>
            <schedule>
                <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
            </schedule>
            <run>
                <model>M2ePro/Cron_Type_Magento::process</model>
            </run>
        </M2ePro_cron>
    </jobs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the version 6.1.1 M2E uses its own cron system (not Magento cron). The synchronization tasks are now initiated from M2E pro server. Automatic synchronization is launched every 5 minutes. No additional settings are required for it to be set up.
As you told that you have version 6.2.3 then Synchronization should be there automatically. In case if automatic synchronization does not occur then you have to run cron manualy. I had got same problem in my last project. I resolved this problem using following way:

**Open Cpanel and add a cron job.**

**Command PHP:  php -q /%PATH_MAGENTO_ROOT_CATALOG%/cron.php -mdefault 1**

OR

**Command GET:  GET http://%YOUR_DOMAIN%/cron.php**

It is strongly recommended to set up `cron`job to run every 1 minute (e.g. * * * * *).

In my case, I applied php command i.e.

**php -q /%PATH_MAGENTO_ROOT_CATALOG%/cron.php -mdefault 1**

Now, after this if you want to test your cron is running or not then go to

**/app/code/community/Ess/M2ePro/Model/Cron/Type**

there is a file named as Abstract.php which contains a function `process()` on line no. 20

You can put a `mail()` function there and check email id. If you get email after each minute interval then means your `cron` is running fine. Good Luck